# Could someone explain how this code (struct in Dart and fetching values from JSON) works and how it actually works?

Tags: flutter, dart, class, struct

This is the code:

```
class Event {
    final String id;
    final String name;
    final String description;
    final String date;
    final String imgPath;

    const Event({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.description,
        required this.date,
        required this.imgPath,
    });

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return switch (json) {
        {
          "id": String id,
          "name": String name,
          "description": String description,
          "date": String date,
          "imgPath": String imgPath,
        } =>
          Event(
            id: id,
            name: name,
            description: description,
            date: date, 
            imgPath: imgPath
          ),
        _ => throw const FormatException('Couldn't fetch events'),
      };
  }
}
```

I understand the variable declaration and the `const Event({..})`, however I do not quite understand factory and the shenanigans that go after `return switch (json)`

To my understanding we match variables from JSON with variables in this class and `factory` is to prevent this class from self-initializing? Please correct me if I am wrong, this is the first time I try to create something that functions as struct in Dart.

Comment: Just so you know "struct" is a very C language kind of thing. You shouldn't call it that. It's simply called a class. People not familiar with C wouldn't even understand what you meant with the word struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain it as simple as possible. `Event` is a class. You can create instances of a class by calling a `constructor`. A `factory` is a special kind of way to get an instance of class and will usually call a `constructor` within its body. That's what's happening here. The part with

```
const Event
```

is the contructor. It is passed all the parameters for creating a new instance of an `Event`.

So what's happening in the factory is so called pattern matching and is actually a relative new feature of dart. So it checks the parameter `json` against the pattern

```
    {
      "id": String id,
      "name": String name,
      "description": String description,
      "date": String date,
      "imgPath": String imgPath,
    }
```

Which means, it checks if the map `json` has all the fields with keys "id", "name", "description", "date", "imgPath" and if all their values are of the `String` type. And this will also store those values in local variables as named in the pattern. If the `json` parameter matches this pattern it calls the constructor and uses as arguments the local variables that were matched in the pattern before and returns this instance. If it doesn't match the pattern it will throw the `FormatException`